# how to use internationalization function in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, intl

In my project I'd like tu use the [internationalisation function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) in my twig vue to display a specific country names according to its `locale` in the `app.request.locale`.

I was thinking that [twig-extention](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html) was my solution but only `localizedDate`, `localizedCurrency` and `localizedNumber` are available.

Is there a simple way to use this functionality ?

Comment: I could but the idea is not to write them by myself as they are all included in php `Locale` class

Comment: You can introduce any functionality to Twig using your own extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the recommandation of [emix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997162/emix) and [Yoann Mir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9529649/yoann-mir), I created my own filter (it is more appropriate than a function) that use php locale:

```php
namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Locale;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class CountryExtention extends AbstractExtension
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale){
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('alpha2', [$this, 'getAlpha2code']),
            new TwigFilter('language', [$this, 'getLanguageName'])
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Transform a locale variable in a Alpha2 country code 
     * 
     * @param string $locale the locale to be transformed in RFC 4646
     * 
     * @return string|null the alpha2 code in ISO 639-1
     */
    public function getAlpha2code($locale){

        return Locale::getRegion($locale);
    }

    /**
     * Transform the locale variable in a language name displayed in the current locale
     * 
     * @param string $locale the locale to be transformed in RFC 4646
     * @param string|null $inLocale the target locale to display the language name
     * 
     * @return string|null the language name in the target locale or in the app.locale
     */
    public function getLanguageName($locale, $inLocale = null)
    {
        if (!$inLocale)
            $inLocale = $this->defaultLocale;

        return Locale::getDisplayLanguage($locale, $inLocale); 
    }
}
```

then add it to my services:

```
service:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            $defaultLocale: locale

    App\Twig\CountryExtention:
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extention }
```

and use it in my twig as such:

```html
{% for locale in twig_locales %}
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <span class=" mr-1">
            <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{ locale|alpha2|lower }}"></i>
        </span>
        {{ locale|language(app.request.locale) }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create an extension of your own. Something like that :

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Locale;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class TranslateCountryExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    const COUNTRY_LIST = [
        'AF', 'AX', 'AL', 'DZ', 'AS', 'AD', 'AO', 'AI', 'AQ', 'AG', 'AR', 'AM', 'AW', 'AU', 'AT', 'AZ',
        'BS', 'BH', 'BD', 'BB', 'BY', 'BE', 'BZ', 'BJ', 'BM', 'BT', 'BO', 'BQ', 'BA', 'BW', 'BV', 'BR',
        'IO', 'BN', 'BG', 'BF', 'BI', 'KH', 'CM', 'CA', 'CV', 'KY', 'CF', 'TD', 'CL', 'CN', 'CX', 'CC',
        'CO', 'KM', 'CG', 'CD', 'CK', 'CR', 'CI', 'HR', 'CU', 'CW', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DK', 'DJ', 'DM', 'DO',
        'EC', 'EG', 'SV', 'GQ', 'ER', 'EE', 'ET', 'FK', 'FO', 'FJ', 'FI', 'FR', 'GF', 'PF', 'TF', 'GA',
        'GM', 'GE', 'DE', 'GH', 'GI', 'GR', 'GL', 'GD', 'GP', 'GU', 'GT', 'GG', 'GN', 'GW', 'GY', 'HT',
        'HM', 'VA', 'HN', 'HK', 'HU', 'IS', 'IN', 'ID', 'IR', 'IQ', 'IE', 'IM', 'IL', 'IT', 'JM', 'JP',
        'JE', 'JO', 'KZ', 'KE', 'KI', 'KP', 'KR', 'KW', 'KG', 'LA', 'LV', 'LB', 'LS', 'LR', 'LY', 'LI',
        'LT', 'LU', 'MO', 'MK', 'MG', 'MW', 'MY', 'MV', 'ML', 'MT', 'MH', 'MQ', 'MR', 'MU', 'YT', 'MX',
        'FM', 'MD', 'MC', 'MN', 'ME', 'MS', 'MA', 'MZ', 'MM', 'NA', 'NR', 'NP', 'NL', 'NC', 'NZ', 'NI',
        'NE', 'NG', 'NU', 'NF', 'MP', 'NO', 'OM', 'PK', 'PW', 'PS', 'PA', 'PG', 'PY', 'PE', 'PH', 'PN',
        'PL', 'PT', 'PR', 'QA', 'RE', 'RO', 'RU', 'RW', 'BL', 'SH', 'KN', 'LC', 'MF', 'PM', 'VC', 'WS',
        'SM', 'ST', 'SA', 'SN', 'RS', 'SC', 'SL', 'SG', 'SX', 'SK', 'SI', 'SB', 'SO', 'ZA', 'GS', 'SS',
        'ES', 'LK', 'SD', 'SR', 'SJ', 'SZ', 'SE', 'CH', 'SY', 'TW', 'TJ', 'TZ', 'TH', 'TL', 'TG', 'TK',
        'TO', 'TT', 'TN', 'TR', 'TM', 'TC', 'TV', 'UG', 'UA', 'AE', 'GB', 'US', 'UM', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VU',
        'VE', 'VN', 'VG', 'VI', 'WF', 'EH', 'YE', 'ZM', 'ZW',
    ];

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new TwigFunction('countryList', [$this, 'countryList']),
        );
    }

    public function countryList(string $locale): array
    {
        $translatedCountries = [];

        foreach( self::COUNTRY_LIST as $countryId) {
            $translatedCountries[$countryId] = Locale::getDisplayRegion($countryId);
        }

        return $translatedCountries;
    }
}
```

And use it in your Twig templates like:

```
{% for key, value in countryList(app.locale) %} etc etc ...
```

I don't know about a way to display all Locale class region values so I used a constant.

Comment: I didn't need to translate the whole list of `locales` at once but to use a specific one that is already available in twig. I used your answer to build my two filters. Need to be careful with the `$locale` format, `fr` for example doesn't return anything (should use `fr_FR` instead).